# pessimistic locking and client death

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, locking

We are considering pessimistic locking for our project (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`); as we are used to optimistic locking, we are afraid about the operation of the server being blocked on such a lock (lock not getting released ever).

The most common concern that people have is obviously deadlocks, however we have another concern: what if the client dies, or looses connection to the server, while holding a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` lock?

In many cases it would not be relevant because if the client dies the application dies, however in this case we will have a cluster of servers with failover, so we wouldn't want other nodes in the cluster to be overly affected if one node dies.

On this topic I have found this 2003 message, concerning postgreSQL:
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3E81D7F0.2010604@xythos.com

We have also tested the `tcp_keepalives_idle` postgreSQL configuration parameter, and confirmed that if we leave it low enough and kill the client, the lock gets released. However if we didn't touch that parameter, the lock did not get released (but maybe we didn't wait long enough).
And that's without considering the concern raised by this 2003 message, about the difference between the lifecycle of the client application and the life-cycle of the connection pool (we'll keep the default on this but we expect each node to have its own connection pool, no sharing across the cluster).

The problem gets even more complicated because we intend to support several database servers (at least Microsoft SQL Server and PostgreSQL, possibly Oracle).

Our solution would use JavaEE and Glassfish as an application server.

So to summarize the question: Is it safe to assume that apart from deadlocks, it is not possible that a lock stays held forever, the lock will be released after a reasonably short time (which range of duration?), even in case of a sudden death or loss of connectivity to a client holding a lock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think it's safe to assume locks from dead/vanished clients are released in a bounded and deterministic amount of time with all DBMSes and drivers. You'll need to investigate each configuration separately.

In the case of PostgreSQL you're *generally* but not always OK if you have [TCP keepalives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) set quite aggressively, because:

- If the whole client application process dies but the client host stays up the host's kernel will `RST` the TCP connection as part of process cleanup;
- If the client host dies entirely then it'll stop responding to tcp keepalives; and
- If the client host remains alive but the network fails in one or both directions between client and server then it'll stop responding to tcp keepalives.

However, there are a few cases that will not be handled:

- [Connection pool](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) bugs that result in a connection being returned to the pool with a transaction still open and holding locks;
- Connection pools that don't [`DISCARD ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html) and thus fail to release and reset session-level resources like advisory locks (if you use them);
- App server based applications that 'leak' connections with open transactions so the connection pool can never reclaim them;
- Badly written programs that intentionally hold a transaction open during user "think time" like a dialog box or data entry window, where the user might go away and make a coffee ... or go on holiday for a month;
- Cases where the application process remains in existence but is totally non-responsive due to being `SIGSTOP`ped, having been paused by a debugger, hitting an internal threading deadlock, etc. The OS will keep on responding to tcp keepalives but the app won't respond to Pg protocol messages or advance its work.

In the case of PostgreSQL you can use active lock monitoring to scan for and terminate long running transactions that haven't done anything in a while. In particular, you can deal with `<IDLE> in transaction` sessions by scanning [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) (though it's only possible to do this RELIABLY and EASILY in 9.2). With a bit more effort you can use [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html) to watch for queries blocked on a lock for more than x seconds and kill the session holding the lock, though this can make it hard to run some DDL like index creation.

What you really need is *application level* keepalives, where the app says "Yup, I'm alive and responsive". These are rather harder to implement, though.

One thing that will help is that both [PgBouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) and [PgPool-II](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II) (external connection pools for PostgreSQL) support controls for session and transaction timeouts. We've wanted to implement similar options in the core PostgreSQL for some time, but nobody's come up with a design that's robust enough to handle all the corner cases, so for now your best bet is to use an external pooler. You can do this even if you're also using an application-level connection pool.

On the good news front, PostgreSQL automatically detects and breaks deadlocks between transactions, so one thing you *don't* have to worry about much is deadlocks at the SQL level when using PostgreSQL.

Comment: that is a bit sobering, I was hoping for a more optimistic/simple answer. If we want to protect ourselves from such a problem in a simple way, maybe we could also try to put a limit on the maximum duration a lock can be held? I googled on that topic a little but didn't come very far. Generally speaking I think it can be said that a lock being held a minute or longer is a serious problem and I think it would be acceptable that the transaction is rolled back by the RDBMS. I found timeouts when trying to acquire a lock, but not when you hold a lock and don't release it fast enough.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery There's a patch in the queue for PostgreSQL 9.3 that will add a simple lock timeout. I'm not sure if it'll make it into the 9.3 release yet, but please pipe up on the pgsql-hackers mailing list and *test the patch* if you want it to get into 9.3. In PostgreSQL you can monitor the `pg_locks` view and actively terminate processes that hold locks too long, but it tends to cause issues with DDL and reports.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery Oh, one piece of *good* news for you: Pg auto-detects and breaks deadlocks between transactions. It won't do this where one transaction is waiting for another, only where there's a mutual lock interdependency, eg TX 1 needs lock A and holds B, TX 2 needs lock B and holds A. Nonetheless, it takes care of one major pain point for you; if you deadlock, one transaction gets cancelled and the other completes fine, then you just retry the cancelled transaction.

Answer (score 1):

> So to summarize the question: Is it safe to assume that appart from deadlocks, it is not possible that a lock stays held forever?

Yes, that is a perfectly safe assumption, assuming that programmers don't do stupid things like declining to commit transactions ever.....  Even there systems do eventually reboot.....  OTOH storing locks in rows (which I have seen done).... those can last forever.

> ... and that the lock will be released after a reasonnably short time (which range of duration?), even in case of a sudden death or loss of connectivity to a client holding a lock?

Define "reasonably short."  In general the TCP connection should eventually time out if you have keepalives and the issue is client death and at that point the lock should be released.    The larger issue as Craig notes is in software bugs or when developers do something stupid.

Comment: AFAIK until something tries to send a packet on the connection an established TCP connection will stay open indefinitely. I've certainly had ssh sessions among other things remain open while my laptop was in sleep mode over the weekend. They come back to life as if nothing had changed so long as I get the same IP when the machine resumes.

Comment: By generally short I definitely meant <10 minutes, hopefully closer to 1 minute.